# Gif not running when loading an external page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, jquery

I Have a huge php table and i want Load it via AJAX to insert a loading gif to the user.
So i'm very noob with this kind of operation and i make a very simple code to do this task.
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#tableDiv").html('<center><img src="images/loader.gif" /></center>');
                $("#tableDiv").load("regulatoryData.php");
            });
```

This is loading the gif but it is not running, it remains static.
How can i correct it?
Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** When i drag my image to the browser it animates normally.

**EDIT 2:** Whit just the

`$("#tableDiv").html('<center><img src="images/loader.gif" /></center>');`

The gif works fine but when i add the second part its starts to run and just after it stops and remain freezed until the regulatoryData appears

**EDIT 3:** Actually  i checked that is not the gif that is freezing but the entire browser.

Sorry about my english :/

Comment: If you request the image directly in your browser, does it run then?
If you are on a mobile device, it might cause issues because not all mobile browsers support animated gifs

Comment: Can you drag the image in to a browser window and confirm that it animates?

Comment: This question doesn't really seem to have to do with JavaScript, PHP, HTML, or AJAX. Sounds more like there's a problem with your animated GIF.

Comment: When the image is requested in my browser it runs, and when i drag it to the browser it runs too.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/NeFaz/1/

```
<a href="#" id="load">Load</a>
<div id="myid">
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#load").click(function() {
        $('#myid').addClass('loading');
        $("#myid").load('http://www.confetti.co.uk/shop/', function () {
            $('#myid').removeClass('loading');
        });
    });
});
```

---

```
#myid {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
#myid.loading {
    background-image: url('http://koikoikoi.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/RESET.gif');
}
```

This sets the image as a background of the div, but only when a class is applied. We start without this class.

Upon click the load link, we add the loading class to the div and the bg image will display. The function that is used on load fires upon the load finishing, and removes the class from the div therefore removing the image.

Comment: When i use     '$("#tableDiv").html('<center><img src="images/loader.gif" /></center>');'
it works fine... but when i add the $("#tableDiv").load("regulatoryData.php");
it starts to run and stops remaining freeze until the other page loads

Comment: I've updated to a suggestion that should get around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add at the beginning of `<BODY>`

```
<img src="images/loader.gif" style="display:none" />
```

As a "pre-loader"

Comment: I think you forgot to write the rest of your answer

Comment: No. I think the problem is: the ajax ending before loading gif. Then you can put an image with 'display: none' just to make the browser load it. With this (I think) the original code will work.

Comment: You're still not making a lot of sense. The image not loading isn't a problem - the browser is hanging

Comment: Sometimes (usually in <a> click) the browser will stop loading the page, and gif can show only one frame, like a png. Do not know if that's because he's using ajax. But if it is a pre-load the gif can help. See it only as a suggestion, not an absolute answer

Comment: Thank you for the replies but the problem is when i try to load the external page, the browser crashes for a moment and so the gif stop running.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that IE stops animating GIFs when you start loading another page. I've solved that in one of my own projects by adding a timeout that refreshes the image source 50 ms after the other page starts loading by just assigning it the same value again. In your case that would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tableDiv").html('<center><img src="images/loader.gif" /></center>');
            setTimeout(function() { $("#tableDiv img").attr("src", "images/loader.gif"); }, 50);
            $("#tableDiv").load("regulatoryData.php");
        });
```

Comment: Actually i checked that is not the gif that is freezing but the entire browser.